# Phonegap create command generating empty project

Tags: android, cordova

Am following the phonegap guide for android [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android.)

I've being able to set up all the paths for java, ant, and the sdk.
After running the `create <project_folder_path> <package_name> <project_name>` command like is stated in the tutorial.
I get message saying its generating the project, after its done and i navigate to the project folder, the cordova.jar and cordova.js files are missing.

Do i have to do something extra ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Is this on Windows?  For the time being you should be able to create a project manually like in: http://www.axattechnologies.com/creating-the-project-in-android-using-phone-gap/

Comment: yes this happens on windows